# Read browser certificates in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

How do we read the certificates present in the browser's cert store in C#?
After clicking on the highlighted button in the image, ALL the SSL certs can be seen in the popup in browsers settings

[image: Screenshot from Settings page of Google Chrome Browser]
After clicking on the highlighted button ALL the SSL certs can be seen in the popup in browsers settings, how do we read these SSL certificates in C#?

Comment: It's not browser cert store it's windows cert store (personal) - you can use X509Store class

Comment: I had tried with windows personal cert for current user.If we deploy the app in any server it tries to read the certificate fro that server instead of getting it from the machine we hit the URL. I need to app to take add cert to the request only form the base machine of the user not from the server.